# Why does $\int ^{\pi/2}_0 \sin^7(x)\cos^5(x)dx = \frac{1}{120}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have worked through the problem, and I am having trouble figuring out why $\int ^{\pi/2}_0 \sin^7(x)\cos^5(x)dx = \frac{1}{120}$. That's what my textbook says it equals.

**Here are my steps:**

$$\int ^{\pi/2}_0 \sin^7(x)\cos^5(x)dx$$

$$=\int ^{\pi/2}_0 (1-\cos^6(x))\cos^5(x)\sin(x)dx$$

Let $u=\cos(x)$

Then $du = -\sin(x)dx$ and $dx = \frac{-1}{\sin(x)} du$

$$\int^{\pi/2}_0 (1 - u^6)u^5 \sin(x) \frac{-1}{\sin(x)}du$$

$$=-\int^{\pi/2}_0 (u^5-u^{11})du$$

$$=-[\frac{\cos^6(x)}{6}-\frac{\cos^{11}(x)}{11} |^{\pi/2}_0]$$

$$= -[0 - (\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{11})]$$

$$= -[-(\frac{11}{66}-\frac{6}{66})]$$

$$=-(\frac{-5}{66})$$

$$=\frac{5}{66}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to go overkill, you can use the Beta Function.

Comment: @TomHimler Thank you, but I am taking a Calculus 2 class, and I want to do what the rest of the class is doing.

Comment: No worries just thought I'd put that out there for curious minds :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also go for $\cos x$:
$$\int ^{\pi/2}_0 \sin^7(x)\cos^5(x)dx=\int ^{\pi/2}_0 \sin^7x\cdot (1-\sin ^2x)^2\cdot \cos x\, dx\stackrel{t=\sin x}=\\
\int_0^1t^7(1-t^2)^2dt=\int_0^1(t^7-2t^9+t^{11})dt=\\
\left(\frac{t^8}8-\frac{t^{10}}{5}+\frac{t^{12}}{12}\right)|_0^1=\frac18-\frac15+\frac1{12}=\frac1{120}.$$

Answer (score 8):

It is not true that $\sin^6{x} = 1-\cos^6{x}$. Instead, you have
$$ \sin^2{x} = 1-\cos^2{x} \implies \sin^6{x} = (\sin^2{x})^3 = (1-\cos^2{x})^3 . $$
So you instead should have
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} (1-\cos^2{x})^3 \cos^5{x} \sin{x} \, dx . $$
Now your substitution should work and give the right answer.

Comment: Maybe I'm still doing something wrong, but I'm getting $\frac{5}{14}$ as the answer. Let $u=\cos(x)$ $\int^{\pi/2}_0 (1-u^2)^3u\sin(x)\frac{-1}{\sin(x)}du=-\int^{\pi/2}_0 (u-u^6)du=-[0-(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{7})]$

Comment: @LuminousNutria $(1-u^2)^3 u \neq u-u^6$...

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^5\cos(x)^7\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{\pi}{2}-x}{=}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^7\cos(x)^5\,dx $$
hence by averaging the two integrals
$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^5\cos(x)^5\left[\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)\right]\,dx = \frac{1}{2^6}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^5(2x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2^7}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^5(x)\,dx, $$
$$ I = \frac{1}{2^7}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^5(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2^6}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^5(x)\,dx.$$

The last integral is readily computed from $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)$, the binomial theorem and the values of $\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{nix}e^{-mix}\,dx$, or just by integration by parts. Yet another way is to exploit the Beta function identity
$$ \int_{0}^{1} u^{\alpha}(1-u)^{\beta}\,du = \frac{\alpha!\beta!}{(\alpha+\beta+1)!}=\frac{1}{(\alpha+\beta+1)\binom{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha}} $$
through the direct substitution $x=\arcsin\sqrt{u}$.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing a cubic, we could do a quadratic:

The differential is $$\sin^7x\cos^5x\mathrm dx.$$ Write this as $$\sin^7x\cos^4x\cos x\mathrm dx=\sin^7x\cos^4x\mathrm d(\sin x)=\sin^7x(1-\sin^2x)^2\mathrm d(\sin x)=\sin^7x(1-2\sin^2x+\sin^4x)^2\mathrm d(\sin x),$$ and you may now complete it.

Comment: +1 WOW !!! $\mbox{}\mbox{}\mbox{}\mbox{}$